# How to filter an empty XML element using LinQ in WinRT?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-8, windows-runtime

**What I want**
retrieve task whch "due" element is overdue.

**What the XML is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tasks>
  <task>    
    <title>11111</title>
    <due>2012/06/18</due>
  </task>
  <task>
    <title>2121211212</title>    
    <due></due>
  </task>
</tasks>
```

**What I code**

```
        var res = from q in xml.Root.Descendants("task")
                  where q.Element("due").IsEmpty == false & (Convert.ToDateTime(q.Element("due").Value)).Date < DateTime.Now.Date
                  select q
```

**What the error is**

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> > Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
> >     If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

**-_-**
If I delete the task which element"due" is empty, the error went away.
but Don't I just filter the empty element with the code below?!

```
q.Element("due").IsEmpty == false
```

Why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [`XElement.IsEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.isempty.aspx)

> Note that an element that contains a start and end tag with no content between the tags is not considered to be an empty element. It has content with no length. Only an element that contains only a start tag, and is expressed as a terminated empty element, is considered to be empty.

You could use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to check whether the element contains text characters:

```
var res = from q in xml.Root.Descendants("task")
          where q.Element("due").IsEmpty == false &&
                string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(q.Element("due").Value) == false &&
                Convert.ToDateTime(q.Element("due").Value).Date < DateTime.Now.Date
          select q
```